# Apache authz provider module: r->server->server_scheme is (null)

Tags: apache, http, authorization, uri, apache-modules

I have an Apache module which is an authz_provider. In this module, I have `request_rec *r`. I need to get an URI scheme used (i.e. "http", "https"...). However, `r->server->server_scheme` is `(null)`.

Why is that? And is there any other way to get the used scheme?

Answer (score 0):

```
ap_http_scheme(r)
```

is the answer.

Still, I am not sure under which circumstances the server_scheme variable would contain something else than (null).